# C# Make list instance using string value

Tags: c#

I have a variable like below

```
string typeName1 = "List<int>";
string typeName2 = "List<string>";
```

I want to get a list of object from `typeName1`, `typeName2`

```
object typeName1Obj =(make object from typeName1); // List<int> instance
object typeName2Obj =(make object from typeName2); // List<string> instance
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? While this is possible using reflection, I have to ask: What is your goal here? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Possible via reflection, e.g. using [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance).

Comment: we have some xml file and xml file has some function name and parameter info. To call function from function name, i can do method reflection. but i need to make parameter. So i need to make parameter type from string.

Comment: You are going to be fighting a loosing battle here. if you have a relatively small amount of types, just use a switch or  `if (typeName1 == "List<int>") { return new List<int>() }` Sure you can parse the type, and check for this and that, `MakeGenericType` and then `CreateInstance` but this is going to be a lot of hassle

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able create a `List<int>` from string you need the following:

```
var intCollectionType = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]");
var intCollectionInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(intCollectionType);
```

You have use to

- `System.Int32` rather than `int`
- `1[...] rather than <...>
- `System.Collections.Generic.List` rather than `List`

---

**UPDATE #1**
Adding item to the newly created collection

```
var addMethod = intCollectionType.GetMethod("Add");
addMethod.Invoke(intCollectionInstance, new object[] { 1 });
```

Comment: thanks bro. How can i set value to this list?

Comment: You just need to cast to it to `List<int>` and then call `.Add`

Comment: because List<int> is string, i don't have idea..  do you have any idea?

Comment: @사랑방구승윤TV Updated the answer, please check it.